# How can I center an entire paragraph under a table?

Tags: html, css

I'm automating an email which uses HTML as the body.  The only thing in the email will be a table which could have a varying amount of columns depending on the source data, and a paragraph of text below that.  I tried adding a `div` container to encompass the `table` and `p` elements, and then do this in the CSS

```
p {
  text-align:center; 
}
```

Edit:  However, this centers the paragraph in the entire page instead of below the table.  The table doesn't take up the width of the entire page

Comment: is it a email template ?

Comment: did you limit the width of the `div`? by default they'll span the entire width of the container anyways, as will the `p`.

Comment: Yes - Just added an edit.  I've tried a couple things so I got confused, but the CSS above centers the paragraph in the whole page rather than under just the table

Comment: I tried limiting the width of the `div` to 300 px and then 100 px just to see if it worked, but the table ended up the same size (which I know was more than 100 px).  I'm not sure why that didn't work.

Comment: do an outter table with two rows, one for the inner table and other for the centered text below. set up an invisible border

Comment: I would prefer to have a separate paragraph element but if that's the only option I will go with that

Comment: You could also have a surrounding div that contains the table, with `width: auto`, making the div the exact width of the table, and then any paragraph beneath the table, but inside the div, would be centered within the frame of the table.

Comment: Not sure how much support my concept has for older email rendering engines like Outlook though

Comment: That's a good suggestion and I wasn't aware that you could do `div{width:auto;}`, but you're correct that it doesn't seem to work with Outlook (which isn't surprising)